# I installed python3.6 on ubuntu 20.04, but when I type 'python3' or 'pip3' it refers to python 3.8. Uninstall it removes everything from my pc

Tags: python, python3, pip

Edit: Changing the alias of python3 from python 3.8 to python3.6 doesn't work in my pc. It gives no errors, but aftera reboot or logout and login, it changes again to python3.8. Finding for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `python3` for Ubuntu 20.04 is 3.8.2 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3), and it's what the tools of the OS are built for, so removing it would cause every Ubuntu program that requires it to be removed as well. I'm unsure of what you've done to get python 3.6 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3.6) as it's available for Ubuntu 18.04 and not focal/20.04, so more details may help me at least to understand (esp. uninstall step makes me think you've installed not just used `alias`).

Comment: I am learning Tensorflow... It works with python3.8.2 but the version is 2.2.0. And it needs AVX instruction set inbuilt with the processor... But I have a pretty old pc , so I need to install Tensorflow 1.5.0, and that needs python3.6, and after installing that I went in this mess. BTW thanks for your answer

Comment: It is better that you compile python 3.6 from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the shell writing `python3.6` instead of `python3`.

If you want to open python3.6 every time you write `python` in the shell, you can establish the default python executable with update-alternatives as follows:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

If you want to change the default again, you can simply write:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

and insert the number related to the version you want to use.

Comment: I get: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python